# How can I make a counter based on the amount of triggers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I wanted to make a counter that counts how many times the player hitted a "player_grower". But the problem I'm getting that it isn't counting futher then 1.

```
public class Collision_Player_grower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player_grower;
    public float times_player_grower;

    void Start()
    {
        times_player_grower = 0;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            print("we hit an playergrower");
            Destroy(Player_grower);
            times_player_grower = times_player_grower + 1;
            print("times hit =" + times_player_grower);
        }
    }
    void Update ()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The result this gives me is that it prints: "times hit = 1", even when I hit two or more of those objects. I believe this happens because it doesn't save the value but I'm not sure.

How can I fix this?

Comment: On a tangent: why is your counter a float?

Comment: cause its stores numeric values

Comment: But if it's a count of interactions, it's by definition a number without a decimal part i.e. an integer.

Comment: no? it only counts whole objects, every trigger the value increases by 1, is doesnt reach the decimal parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your `Collision_Player_grower` instances have their own respective field

```
public float times_player_grower;
```

so this is an individual counter for each of them.

You probably would make it [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) so it is "shared" among them all

```
// I also think an int would be probably more appropriate for your use case
public static int times_player_grower;
```

---

Or as an alternative - and cleaner in my eyes - would be to rather let the player itself track the collisions and count.

You either keep your current code but let the player store according value:

```
// Script on your player object
public class PlayerHitCountController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int times_player_grower;
}
```

and then do

```
public class Collision_Player_grower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player_grower;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.TryGetComponent<PlayerHitCountController>(out var hitCounter))
        {
            print("we hit an playergrower");
            Destroy(Player_grower);
            hitCounter.times_player_grower += 1;
            print("times hit =" + hitCounter.times_player_grower);
        }
    }
}
```

Or and that would be my actual approach go the total other way round.

```
// If Player_grower is the same as the object this script is attached to than probably you wouldn't need it
public class Collision_Player_grower : MonoBehaviour
{
    // does nothing but holding the information

    public GameObject Player_grower;
}

// Script on your player object
public class GrowCollisionChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int times_player_grower;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent<Collision_Player_grower>(out var grower))
        {
            print("we hit an playergrower");
            Destroy(grower.Player_grower);
            // Or if Player_grower is the same object as this is attached to anyway
            //Destroy(grower.gameObject);
            times_player_grower += 1;
            print("times hit =" + times_player_grower);
        }
    }
}
```

This way your player has the full control over the counter and can e.g. also reset it where needed.

Comment: @Remco.d.jong wasn't this the first thing I told you to do? Way before the accepted answer was even added ^^

Comment: yeah my bad haha, I didnt saw the first 2 lines of your answer whoops

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are trying to count the triggers per `Player_grower`. What is happening is the following: let's say you have 5 `Player_grower` objects. 1 of them gets triggered. It is calling the `OnTriggerEnter()` on that particular object setting `times_player_grower` to 1 and then immediately destroying the object. Even though the `Destroy` statement is before the incremente and `print` statments Unity still executes everyting before destroying the object (calling `Destroy` only marks the object to get destroyed at the end of the frame, until then everything runs). So this is why it always prints 1.

Now to answer your problem - `times_player_grower` variable exists on every grower but you need to have it declared only 1 time, like a "global" variable instead of "local" for every object so that it will keep counting and not get destroyed together with the GameObject. Now there is 2 ways of achieving this:

The first one is to make the variable static like this: `public static float times_player_grower;` what `static` is doing here is declaring a shared variable across all instances of the `Collision_Player_grower`. All the objects of class `Collision_Player_grower` will have a common variable called `times_player_grower`. This way the variable does not get destroyed when the object gets destroyed and you can do your count there. You MUST research [static variables](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity%20static%20variable) if you don't know what they are.

Second one is keeping a count in a separate GameObject that does not get destroyed duing the trigger event.

Good luck

Comment: I did some research tot static variables and I think it does just what I need, thanks!

Comment: @Remco.d.jong also note that if you go with static variables you need to manually reset them before each game/scene/session because they will not get reset themselves.

Comment: So it isn't possible to write something like: void Respawn() {times_player_grower = 0}?